# C# Generics : CS0311 when implementing generic class that meets a generic interface contract

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have searched around and found one somewhat relevant answer but, for the life of me, I still cannot figure out where I'm going wrong! I am trying to implement some generically typed tree data structures, using code similar to that below, but I get compiler error CS0311.

> *error CS0311: The type 'Test.TestType' cannot be used as type parameter 'K' in the generic type or method 'Test.TreeIndex<K>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Test.TestType' to 'Test.IIndexable<Test.TestType>'.*

I just can't figure out why the compiler doesn't know how to deal with this so any clues would be much appreciated.

```cs
public interface IIndexable<K> where K : IComparable
{
    byte[] ToBytes();
    K FromBytes(byte[] bytes);
}

public class TestType : IIndexable<byte>, IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(object b)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        return new byte[1];
    }

    public byte FromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class TreeIndex<K> where K : IComparable, IIndexable<K>
{
    public int SomeMethod(K a, K b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TreeIndex<TestType> treeIndex = new TreeIndex<TestType>(); // CS0311 generated twice here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TreeIndex<K>` class requires `K` implement `IIndexable<K>`, so `TestType` should implement `IIndexable<TestType>` instead of `IIndexable<byte>`

```
public class TestType : IIndexable<TestType>, IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(object b)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        return new byte[1];
    }

    public TestType FromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider using the generic `IComparable<T>` constraint on your `IIndexable<K>` interface i.e.

```
public interface IIndexable<K> where K : IComparable<K>
{
    byte[] ToBytes();
    K FromBytes(byte[] bytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the second idea as well

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the following generic constraint

`public class TreeIndex<K> where K : IComparable, IIndexable<K>`

And you´re declaring
`TreeIndex<TestType>`

You're saying that `TestType` implements `IIndexable<TestType>`, which cannot be true.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the compiler to make a `new TreeIndex<TestType>()`

The definition for TreeIndex is `TreeIndex<K> where K : IComparable, IIndexable<K>` which means that the type you pass for the generic must be of `IIndexable<K>`.

So when you say: `TreeIndex<TestType>` then the compiler expects `TestType` to be of type `IIndexable<K>`, where `K` is `TestType`, so it expects `TestType` to implement `IIndexable<TestType>`, which it does not. It implements `IIndexable<byte>` instead.

---

It is hard to tell what the best solution would be for your case, but one way to solve it is to specify 2 generics:

```
// change the TreeIndex definition to take 2 generic types
public class TreeIndex<K, Y>
    where K : IComparable, IIndexable<Y>
    where Y : IComparable

...

// specify both generic types
TreeIndex<TestType, byte> treeIndex = new TreeIndex<TestType, byte>();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`Compiler Error CS0311`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384252.aspx)

> When a constraint is applied to a generic type parameter, an implicit
>   identity or reference conversion must exist from the concrete argument
>   to the type of the constraint. To correct this error
>
> Change the argument you are using to create the class.
>
> - Change the argument you are using to create the class.
> - If you own the class, you can remove the constraint or else do something to enable an implicit reference or identity conversion. For
>     example, you can make the second type inherit from the first

Based on that, `TreeIndex<K>` class have to implement `IIndexable<TestType>` not `IIndexable<byte>`.

When you write `TreeIndex<TestType>` compiler asks for `IIndexable<K>` which means `IIndexable<TestType>` on your case.

But your `TestType` class doesn't implement `IIndexable<TestType>`. It implements `IIndexable<byte>`.